# jQuery Selector and php loop

Tags: php, jquery-selectors

I have a PHP loop like this `<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>` now inside this loop I will be creating some `div`. the number of `div`s created depends on number of products. Also, I have a javascript function that creates a countdown.

Now I am trying to create a unique countdown in every div that gets created. .ie unique countdown for every product. here is the code that generates the coundown

```
$(function(){$('.counter').countdown({startTime:"<?php echo $product['time']; ?>" });});
```

and this is what I have inside the php loop that creates the divs

```
<div class= 'counter' ></div>
```

now what this gives me is the same counter in all the divs. I'm new to all this, I haven't slept in hours trying to learn and figure out what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:

So I still have not get what I want. 
    $('.counter').each(function() { $(this).countdown(....
produce the same counter for all the divs. and for some reason I get syntax error when I try to use 
    $('#product-').countdown(... 
in order to create a unique selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work as the selector *.counter* will find *all* elements with the class name *counter*.

Assuming that time varies for every product and that you have a unique identifier for every product, you *could* solve this by assigning an unique ID to every div-element, and use this as a means to trigger the countdown process:

```
<div id="product-<?php echo $product['id']; ?>" class="counter"></div>
```

And the Javascript-code:

```
$('#product-<?php echo $product['id']; ?>').countdown({startTime: '...'});
```

I'd suggest a design pattern though where you don't have to generate javascript code like this.

Comment: what do you mean to design a pattern ? you were right by the way.

Comment: I am trying to follow your suggestion. but $('#product-<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>') gives me an error.

Comment: I know too little of your source code to be able to determine what is wrong. A syntax error means that there is a syntactical error somewhere in your _Javascript_ code. Make sure to examine the generated jQuery thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you Zanathel. For some reason when ever I tried to use the product id inside the selector , I get a syntax error. What I ended up doing was I created a count++ inside my for loop and used that instead of the product id to create the unique selectors. But Thank you, your method was What I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is each()

```
$('.counter').each(function() { $(this).countdown({startTime:"" }); });
```